# PostGIS create view outputs without projection

Tags: qgis, postgis, coordinate-system, postgresql

I uploaded a shapefile through the postGUI. It contains an EPSG code projection. When I want to create a view based on a selection of N-South roads. What is missing?

```
CREATE VIEW shapefiles."roads_NS" AS
SELECT *
FROM shapefiles."roads"
WHERE orientation = 'NS';
```

My schema is called shapefiles, and the shapefile table is named roads
I am not sure how to check projection in PostGIS but with the QGIS plugin it is apparent it is unprojected, and when I try to do an intersection on this buffer output it gives me an error saying the buffered roads table is unprojected. Also in all of the tutorials I never see anyone use the schema."tablename" syntax but not work unless I use that formal structure.

Comment: you must add the schema to your user `search_path` to be able to query its content without specifying the schema name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You check the projection/SRID of your table using the [PostGIS metadata table](http://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/geometries.html#metadata-tables) `geometry_columns`:

```
SELECT * FROM geometry_columns
```

You can also check the SRID of individual rows in your table:

```
SELECT ST_SRID(geom) FROM shapefiles."roads"
```

This is assuming that your geometry column is called `geom`. You can set the projection using function [ST_SetSRID](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_SetSRID.html), eg. `ST_SetSRID(geom, 4326)`, if your projection is EPSG:4326.

In order to use the view you have created, the SRID should be set on the original table. You can update your table using:

```
UPDATE shapefiles."roads" SET geom=ST_SetSRID(geom, 4326).
```

Answer (score 3):

You can cast the geometry column to the desired type/crs.

```sql
CREATE VIEW myview AS 
SELECT
   id,
   --all other fields
   geometry::geometry(LINESTRING, 4326) as geom
FROM shapefiles."roads"
WHERE orientation = 'NS';
```